# Python: Numpy, the data genfromtxt cannot do tranpose

Tags: python, csv, numpy

for example, if I have a data.csv file, it looks like:

```
    A   B
1|  1   2
2|  3   4
```

if I load this data this way:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as text:
    b = np.genfromtxt(   StringIO(text.read()), 
                         delimiter=",",
                         dtype = [('x', int), ('y', int)]) ##<=== in my case
                         ## I want may columns dtype
                         ## in different format
print b.tranpose()
```

it still gives me like this, which is not been transposed.

```
[(1,2) 
 (3,4)]
```

But if I do: dtype = 'str' (which means all columns with same format
np.transpose() works good.

===============================================

But if I do it this way like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)])
print a.transpose()
```

it works correctly

======= MY QUESTION =======
If I load numpy data from txt or csv, and define each columns' data type. Is there any way to make the numpy data working properly?

Comment: Your first code example is **not what you're actually running**, because it misspells the `transpose` function and will not print anything at all. Please post **an example that actually gives the output you claim.**

Comment: Aside: it's usually a better idea to copy and paste the raw csv text itself.  I don't know if your "csv" doesn't have commas, or if it does and you decided to remove them for some reason, making your example inconsistent with your code or not.

Comment: Have tried to print `b` and `b.shape`?

Comment: Can you just tell me how to convert a [(), (), ()] to a numpy array [[], [], []]?? Because I only get [(),(),()] after applying numpy.genfromtxt()

Comment: You have a [record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), that is slightly different than a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is designed to do, see [document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html)

> `T`    Same as `self.transpose()`, except that self is returned if self.ndim < 2.

Here you have `ndim` of `1` for the `b` `array` (you may think it has a shape of `(2,2)` but it has a shape of `(2,)`, be aware), so `T` returns itself.

Comment: I mean, if I use dtype = 'str', the self.ndim do equal to 2. But if I use dtype = [('name1', type1), ('name2', type2) ...] then this not gonna work.